# How to show Checkbox in Advanced PDF?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I need to show the checkbox in Advanced PDF, checked/Unchecked based on the selection on Netsuite form. I did try doing this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="isretired" checked="true"/>
```

This works, but it's changeable, user can change the value (check or uncheck) on the PDF, while i want it for just viewing purposes, whatever is selected in the NetSuite Form.
Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I added two images Checked Checkbox and unchecked Checkbox and show whatever is selected  in Netsuite form. I'm not sure if it the best approach but it worked for me.